# Ruby Enumerator class

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I've read about Enumerator class. And I can't fully understand what's going on here:

`[0, 1].each { |i| puts i }`

By itself `[0, 1].each` returns `=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1]:each>`

So the question is Are we pathing block to `each` method of the array or to the instance of the Enumerator class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many other methods, [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-each) returns and [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerator.html) if a block is not passed but it iterates over the array and calls the block for each item if a block is passed.

The values returned by the block for each array item are the elements of the array returned by `Array#each` when a block is passed.

To answer your question, the block and the `Enumerator` never met.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments (including blocks) to objects. The only things that can take arguments (including blocks) are message sends and blocks. So, obviously, it has to be the former.